# how to reduce echo/noise in PJSIP android application when turn on speaker

Tags: android, pjsip, csip-simple

I have a PJSIP library used in my android based csipsimple application. Everything is working fine except one issue. When i turn on speaker there are lots of echo/noise in the call and it impossible to have conversation. What could be an issue and how to deals with this?

Comment: can you describe briefly with code you are using to reduce the noise.

Comment: I am using PJSIP library with JNI and JAVA code in android application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple google search returns the [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/csipsimple-sipdroid-background-noise-t2548833) which says the possible cause and the solution.

I quote the answer given by gtj0

> In CSipSimple, go to Settings, press the Menu button and set Expert Mode.
>   Then in Settings, Media...set
>
> - Echo cancellation on
> - Echo mode to WebRTC
> - Noise reduction on
> - Clock rate to 16khz
>
> Scroll to the bottom and select Audio troubleshooting then set
>
> - Use WebRTC implementation on
> - Restart stream when change routing on
> - Audio implementation to OpenSL-ES
>
> You can also try different settings for Audio mode for SIP calls. IN_CALL seems to work for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me go through it, and check.

Comment: @DhananjayKashyap : Sure. Go through it and update your findings here.

Comment: Its working great for me as of now. I am looking for more best options.